# Navigating to a URL using webdriver

Tags: selenium

I made a new setup of selenium web-driver for Java on a machine and added all the required jars. Also I installed the Firefox browser on the machine.

However, when I ran a simple Java test script the web-driver opened a Firefox browser but failed to navigate to the URL. When I set the Firefox profile it navigated to the URL. What could be the reason for this? I have a proxy server. Is it because of absence of default Firefox profile?

```java
public class TestClass {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String baseUrl = "google.com";;
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.get(baseUrl); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        String expectedTitle = "Google";
        if(actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)) {
            System.out.println("Test case passed!!!");
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("Test case failed......");
            System.out.println(actualTitle);
        }
        driver.quit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: provide some code and exceptions if any detected?

Answer (score 2):

Always remember adding `http://` before your URL. That's a big thing that someone misses at start.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code which you are writing that will help us to resolve your query. In the meanwhile you can use the below code to navigate to the desired URL :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
```

If this is also not working then its might be incompatibility issue. You have to check your browser compatibility.

Comment: public class TestClass
{ 

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {    
  String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get(baseUrl);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  
  String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
  String expectedTitle = "Google";
  
  if(actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle))
  {
   System.out.println("Test case passed!!!");
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("Test case failed......");
   System.out.println(actualTitle);
  }    
  
  driver.quit();

 }

}

Comment: try to write String baseUrl = "http://google.com"; and you have added two semicolon. Please remove one.

Answer (score 0):

The error that gets thrown to your console is probably 
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Target URL google.com is not well-formed.`

As others have mentioned, and as this exception (in a way) tries to show is that something is missing in your URL. I had this problem a lot, and it is easily fixed by adding `http://` or `https://` to your url. Just try to remember to always add that.